# sequential access file in vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a program in Visual Basic that incorporates using a sequential access file for a ballot type program. Each type the user clicks the save vote button, the amount of votes gets stored. What I am trying to do is in my access file is to display the number of votes as an actual number. The way my program is written right now, the name of the candidate appears as many times as the vote was saved. for example, if perez was voted for 4 times, in the access file perez is displayed on 4 different lines. How do I display the actual number of how many time they were voted for. I'm thinking using a counter variable, but not really sure how to really implement it in. this is what i have so far.

```
Public Class Voter

Dim file As IO.File

Dim infile As IO.StreamReader

Dim outfile As IO.StreamWriter



Private Sub Voter_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    outfile = IO.File.CreateText("Votes.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub btnVote_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVote.Click
    lstResult.Items.Clear()
    'which buttons is clicked
    If radMark.Checked = True Then
        outfile.WriteLine(radMark.Text)
        radMark.Checked = False
    ElseIf radSheima.Checked = True Then
        outfile.WriteLine(radSheima.Text)
        radSheima.Checked = False
    ElseIf radSam.Checked = True Then
        outfile.WriteLine(radSam.Text)
        radSam.Checked = False
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You should select one among them")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnResult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResult.Click
    'Dim Mark, Sheima, Sam As Integer
    Dim Mark As Integer = 0
    Dim Sheima As Integer = 0
    Dim Sam As Integer = 0
    Dim name As String
    'Mark = Sheima = Sam = 0
    outfile.Close()
    infile = IO.File.OpenText("Votes.txt")
    'keep track of votes
    While Not infile.EndOfStream
        name = infile.ReadLine()
        If name.Equals("Mark Stone") Then
            Mark += 1
        ElseIf name.Equals("Sheima Patel") Then
            Sheima += 1
        Else
            Sam += 1
        End If
    End While
    'results
    lstResult.Items.Clear()
    lstResult.Items.Add("Mark Stone     " & CStr(Mark))
    lstResult.Items.Add("Shemia Patel   " & CStr(Sheima))
    lstResult.Items.Add("Sam Perez      " & CStr(Sam))
    infile.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your btnVote_Click function you are writing the radiobutton text into the file everytime you click on it, that's how the issue to be created.

Also you are counting how many times the name appears in the file as the number of vote but not the number.

You should try putting the name and count in your vote file rather than just the name, e.g.

Mark,1
Sheima,2
Same,5

Then when you click Vote button, you should read the number for Mark, increment by 1 and write it back.

Try this,

```
Private Sub btnVote_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVote.Click
    lstResult.Items.Clear()
    'which buttons is clicked
    If radMark.Checked = True Then
        AddCount(radMark.Text)
        radMark.Checked = False
    ElseIf radSheima.Checked = True Then
        AddCount(radSheima.Text)
        radSheima.Checked = False
    ElseIf radSam.Checked = True Then
        AddCount(radSam.Text)
        radSam.Checked = False
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You should select one among them")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnResult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResult.Click

    'results
    lstResult.Items.Clear()
    lstResult.Items.Add("Mark Stone     " & GetCount(radMark.Text))
    lstResult.Items.Add("Shemia Patel   " & CStr(radSheima.Text))
    lstResult.Items.Add("Sam Perez      " & CStr(radSam.Text))

End Sub

Private Sub AddCount(Byval VoteName As String)

    infile = New IO.File.StreamReader("Votes.txt")

    Dim whole_line As String
    Dim person As String
    Dim vote_count As Integer
    Dim found as boolean

    'read through the whole file until the end or find the name
    Do While infile.Peek() >= 0 And person <> VoteName

        'read each line
        whole_line = infile.ReadLine

        person = Split(whole_line, ",")(0)

        If person = VoteName Then

            vote_count = Split(whole_line, ",")(1)


            found = True
        End If
    Loop

    'Close the file after it is used.
    infile.Close()


    'Reopen the file with the StreamWriter
    outfile = IO.File.OpenText("Votes.txt")

    If found = True Then
        'the line will only be replace if the person name is found in the line
        whole_line = Whole_line.replace(VoteName & "," & vote_count, VoteName & "," & vote_count + 1)

        'Write back into the file
        outfile.WriteLine(whole_line)
    Else
        'if the vote name is not found in the file
        'Then create a new one
        outfile.WriteLine(VoteName & ",1" & VbCrLf)
    End If

        outfile.Close()

End Sub

Private Function GetCount(Byval VoteName As String)
    infile = New IO.File.StreamReader("Votes.txt")      

    Dim whole_line As String
    Dim person As String
    Dim vote_count As Integer

    'read through the whole file
    Do While infile.Peek() >= 0 And person <> VoteName

        'read each line
        whole_line = infile.ReadLine

        person = Split(Whole_line, ",")(0)

        If person = VoteName Then
            vote_count = Split(whole_line, ",")(1)
        End If
    Loop

    infile.Close()
    Return vote_count
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, that's what I am trying to figure out. how would i be able to do that?

Comment: I tried but when I run the program it says that the file is being used by another process

Comment: This is because you open the file when the program starts and not closing it until you see the result. Try to open the file when it needs and close it immediately after the function. I have changed the code for this.

Comment: So i should be opening the file when the display vote button is clicked then?

Comment: You need to open the file everything before it is read or written, then close it after. So you need to open it in both addCount and getCount function only

Comment: thats what i have and i still get the same error message. cannot access file because it is being used in another process

Comment: Then I think that is because of mine code, I am reading and writing the same file within the same function....let me fix it

Comment: now in the AddCount Sub, I receive an error message for the line 
    outfile = IO.File.OpenText("Votes.txt") which says value of type StreamReader cannot be converted to StreamWriter

Comment: I have changed the way to open the file by StreamReader. Please forgive me as I don't have .Net installed on my PC, so I cannot compile and test.

Comment: i don't have .net installed either, atleast i don't think i do. but everything works fine, but with this code, i'm only able to keep track of the amount of votes for mark. all the other candidates are 0 even after i vote for them when i click my display votes button

Comment: Good to hear that we solved the open file issue. For this, you may need to change the condition for the while loop from `person = VoteName` to `person <> VoteName`, I forget which is correct condition for the do while

Comment: is that for both the AddCount and GetCount?

Comment: well, the file isn't necessarily solved. all that is displayed in the file is the last person that i voted for. for example, i vote once for mark, once for sheima, and vote sam once, but sam is the last person i voted for, that is what shows up when i click the display votes button, and same thing when i open the file as well

Comment: when i use <> in the do while loops, the program crashes

Comment: O...I just forgot the change the `Or` to `And`....let change the do while loop like this `Do While infile.Peek() >= 0 And person <> VoteName` in both AddCount and GetCount functions

Comment: When you only need to write the last person in the file, then it would be a different store, you can totally forget about the While Loop

Comment: ok, that solves the program from crashing, but still when i vote for each person, only the last person i voted for gets saved and stored

Comment: what do you mean forget about the While loop?

Comment: I'm trying to write everyone that was voted for to the file and keep track of how many times each person was voted for, but it's not really doing that right now. for example, i vote for sam 5 times in a row, then i vote for sheima once, the vote for sheima is the only information that is being stored, saved, and written to the file

Comment: If you only write the last person, then how do you cumulate the voting count for other people, do you read it from lstResult?

Comment: Forget about the While Loop means you don't need to read the file by whole loop, because you can use infile.ReadToEnd to get all texts from the file and replace it by the last voted person and the number.

Comment: thats what i am trying to figure out from your coding. with the code that i posted in the beginning, everything was working fine, i could accumulate all the votes for each candidate, but my only problem was i wanted to say how many times each person was voted for in the file. in my coding, each persons name should up x amount of times they were voted for. but i didn't want that. i wanted it to be like Sam, 3.

Comment: this is my example of how i would like to program to look when both the display votes is clicked, and when the file is open. 
Mark Stone 4
Sheima Perze 7
Sam Patel 2

Comment: seems you are putting all voted name and their count into the files in your example, not only the last one. it is confusing me......

Comment: i want all of the names in the file. i never specially said that i wanted the last one only to be entered into the file. i want to keep track of all of their names and all of their votes

Comment: OK, then you still need the while loop

Comment: So after trying my code, you find only the last voted name appears instead of all voted name, don't you?

Comment: i want to be able to read and keep track of all the names and votes, the same way as when i clicked on the display votes button when i first posted. the only thing i wanted to change is how the file is formatted. i want the file to read the name of each person, and also the number of votes

Comment: You need to put the name and the number of votes by a separator on the same row, and put only 1 person per row like my answer, e.g. 
Mark,1
Sheima,2
Sam,3
Then you can use the ReadLine() function from StreamReader, and split the line by comma to find out the person's name and the voted count.